# How to start describing objects having the same structure?

Tags: sentence-construction

There are two objects having the same structure: an object A and an object B.  When describing the structure of the objects A and B, I usually start describing as follows:

> Since the objects A and B have the same structure, only the structure
>   of the object A is described below for the sake of convenience.

I think this sentence is not sophisticated at all. Could you give me advice on how to start the description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing substantially wrong, or even unsophisticated, about your original sentence. I would suggest that the reason you only describe the structure of object A is brevity, rather than convenience. Most people would consider that object A and object B are [proper names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun), and so the definite articles are not necessary.

> Since objects A and B have the same structure, only the structure of object A is described below for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant by '*not sophisticated at all*'. Please find below the possible reconstructions of the sentence:

- > Since both objects, A and B, share the same structure, I have described the structure of object A; as it has no visible variations from that of Object B.
- > Due to the fact that Object A and B have the same structure, here is the structure of object A, from which Object B has no variations at all.
- > Due to the fact that Object A and B have the same structure, a single depiction of either of the objects would suffice. Please find the structure of object A below.

Comment: "...Object A and B has the same structure..." Don't they **have** the same structure

Comment: **no visible variations**... two identical boxes containing different things satisfy this criterion, but the internal structure could be completely different.